# Navigation through Objects in Java

Tags: java, xml, object, arraylist, latex

My aim is to recreate the structure of XML in custom Objects to operate with it further. Actually, I want to have XML as input and produce LaTeX as output. For this task I have implemented principles of JAXB library. But don't think that this is a good idea, because it is not convenient to retain the needed structure of document as output in TeX.

Here is an example of my custom class:

```
public class Section {

    private String title;
    private List<Par> par;
    private List<SubSec> subsec;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = "\\section {" + title + "}";
    }


    public List<Par> getPar() {
        if (par == null) {
            par = new ArrayList<Par>();
        }
         return this.par;
    }

    public List<SubSec> getSubSec() {
        if (subsec == null) {
            subsec = new ArrayList<SubSec> ();
        }
         return this.subsec;
    }

}
```

So I have a list of Section class, which have titles, list of paragraphs (Par) and list of subsections (SubSec) (simplify LaTeX article structure). Paragraphs contain text, but subsection can include also list of paragraphs. 
After XML input I transfer all Data from it in objects, instances of this Classes.

As example:

```
List<Section> listSections = new ArrayList<Section>();

// omitting the actions to recreate the structure and  set values to Objects
// now, to retrieve and write:

for (int j = 0; j < listSections.size(); j++) {
    List<Par> listParText = listSections.get(j).getPar();
    writer.write(listSections.get(j).getTitle());
    writer.newLine();
    for (Par parList : listParText) {
        if (parList.getText() != null) {
            writer.write(parList.getText());
            writer.newLine();
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is, that I can't recreate the structure of the document on the stage custom objects -> TeX. Although the structure is preserved on stage XML - custom objects. In Objects model I have, for example:

```
Section1(title): Par(text), Par(text), Par(text)
Section2(title): Subsection1(title): Par(text), Par(text), Par(text)
                 Subsection2(title): Par(text), Par(text)
Section3(title): Par(text)
```

Is there a way to save this order and get value in the same order to write them to file? Get values with getters and setters is NOT a problem to me, problem to retrieve them with proper order.

**Update**
To clarify the problem, lets suppose every Section contains paragraphs (Par), subsection (SubSec), Tables, Figures in certain order. But obviously Java not allow to make a list like: `List<SubSec, Par, Table, Fig>`. I can put information there in certain order, but not retrieve. Or can I?

Comment: Are you quite sure you want to do this in Java? Handling mixed content is usually much easier in XSLT or XQuery, or if you really don't want to learn a new language, use a generic object model such as JDOM or XOM.

Comment: The problem is, that I transform XML to LaTeX - text format with its own markup. It is very different from XML. My colleague had successfully wrote XSLT for transforming between different XMLs and HTMLs. For Java there was only small work for parsing with Pattern and Matcher. But for transforming to LaTeX XSLT has not much power. For example the big problem is tables, which are very different in this languages and require hard coding.

Comment: Didn't realize with whom speaking about XSLT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work to make a parent class, say DocumentComponent, of which SubSec, Par, Table, and Fig were all subclasses, and then say that a document is an ordered list of DocumentComponents?

Comment: You mean make only one class for all, that contains in Section, and make other other classes extend this parent class? It makes sense, will try.

Comment: Thanks for advice. After adopting this and workaround with class inheritance, I finally can work with Objects and write them to LaTeX like with Java DOM library and XML :)